# Magento 2: What is the "Stored Payment Methods" in my account section?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, vault

I see *"Stored Payment Methods"* option in my account section, but there is not payment method stored.

Please can anyone explain me how to use this option to store payment methods used on the website.

Comment: Magento will show the saved cc here, if you have saved any for future use while checkout

Answer (score 1):

`Stored Payment Methods` functionality is managed by `Magento_Vault` module. Secure vault is used for storing payment information. It will help the customer to do `Instant Purchase` if `Instant Purchase` option is enabled in the backend.

Currently in `Magento 2` by default below payment methods supports `Secure Vault`.

- Braintree Credit Cards
- Braintree with PayPal Enabled
- PayPal Payflow Pro

You can also check `Paypal` and `Braintree` module.xml file both are using `Magento_Vault` module.

You can check below links also for more details:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/account-dashboard-stored-payment-methods.html

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-instant-purchase.html

**Updated**

> Authorize.Net Payment Method that support Vault Integration

https://github.com/pmclain/module-authorizenetcim

hope this help !!

Comment: I am using "Authorize.net Direct Post" payment method on my store, now what should I do to store the details?

Comment: As you can see `Authorize.net Direct Post` method not using `vault` integration. you need to customize module to save card details using its API. you can take reference of braintree module how it is integrated with vault module.

Comment: I have updated answer